# NSwag.MSBuild TypeScript version issues

Tags: typescript, msbuild, nswag

In NSwag Studio there's a flag to use a specific TypeScript version for the generated TypeScript typings/code. Inside my `.csproj` file I'm trying to accomplish the same things but it doesn't seem to have any effect. Here's my MSBuild command:

`<Exec Command="$(NSwagExe_Core20) swagger2tsclient /input:$(OutDir)api.json /output:..\api.ts /generateClientClasses:false /typeScriptVersion:2.4 /dateTimeType:Date /nullValue:Undefined /generateDtoTypes:true /markOptionalProperties:true /generateCloneMethod:true /typeStyle:Class /generateDefaultValues:true /generateConstructorInterface:true" />`

I'm assuming that isn't the correct way of sending the TS version as a parameter to the command line. Does anybody know which is the correct parameter name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Closing. Behind the scenes the generated typing had a bug but not related to the TypeScript version.